# How to get File version in variable using .cmd

Tags: wmic

I used wmic to get the version of a EXE stored in a variable.
It works fine when I execute it from CMD (that I ran as Admin) but when executed either in a .cmd or .bat files (even when ran as admin) the variable is not populated.

This works directly in CMD:

```
set "npver="&for /F "tokens=2delims==" %a in ('wmic datafile where "Name='c:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'" get version /format:list') do set "npver=%a"
```

When I created the .cmd file, I doubled the % signs.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to echo the variable with the command `echo %npver%`

***With Command line :***

```
set "npver="&for /F "tokens=2delims==" %a in ('wmic datafile where "Name='c:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'" get version /format:list') do set "npver=%a"& echo %npver%
```

With a batch file, you should escape the sign percent `%` by adding another one `%%`
and your code should works now with a batch file like this :

***Batch File :***

```bat
@echo off
set "npver="&for /F "tokens=2delims==" %%a in ('wmic datafile where "Name='c:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'" get version /format:list') do set "npver=%%a"
echo %npver%
pause
```

***EDIT : Get_File_Version.bat***

Here is another code in batch more elaborated to get file version of any Application from file list using WMIC.

```bat
@echo off
Mode 75,3 & color 9E
Title Get File Version of any Application from file list using WMIC by Hackoo
::******************************************************************************
REM Just Change this Variable in your case and the script will do the rest (-_°)
Set "RootFolder=%ProgramData%"
::******************************************************************************
:Main
@for %%a in ("%RootFolder%") do set "FolderName=%%~na"
Set "File_Version_List=%~dp0%FolderName%_File_Version_List.txt"
Set "ErrorFile=%~dp0%FolderName%_Error.txt
Set Extensions="*.exe" "*.dll"
If exist "%ErrorFile%" Del "%ErrorFile%"
If exist "%File_Version_List%" Del "%File_Version_List%"
echo(
echo          Please wait a while ... Process to get file version ...
set "BuildLineWith=call :BuildLine "
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CD /D "%RootFolder%"
@for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /b /s %Extensions%') do (
    set "Version="
    Call :Get_AppName "%%F" AppName
    Call :Add_backSlash "%%F"
    Call :GetVersion !Application! Version
    Call :Remove_backSlash !Application!
    If defined Version (
        (
            echo !Application!
            echo !AppName! ==^> !Version!
            %BuildLineWith%*
        )>> "%File_Version_List%"
    ) else (
        (
            echo Version is not defined in !Application!
            %BuildLineWith%#
        )>> "%ErrorFile%"
    )
)
If Exist "%ErrorFile%" Start "" "%ErrorFile%"
If Exist "%File_Version_List%" Start "" /MAX "%File_Version_List%" & Exit
::*******************************************************************
:GetVersion <ApplicationPath> <Version>
Rem The argument %~1 represent the full path of the application
Rem without the double quotes
Rem The argument %2 represent the variable to be set (in our case %2=Version)
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  'wmic datafile where "name='%~1'" get version /format:Textvaluelist 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Add_backSlash <String>
Rem Subroutine to replace the simple "\" by a double "\\" into a String
Set "Application=%1"
Set "String=\"
Set "NewString=\\"
Call Set "Application=%%Application:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Remove_backSlash <String>
Rem Subroutine to replace the double "\\" by a simple "\" into a String
Set "Application=%1"
Set "String=\\"
Set "NewString=\"
Call Set "Application=%%Application:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Get_AppName <FullPath> <AppName>
Rem %1 = FullPath
Rem %2 = AppName
for %%i in (%1) do set "%2=%%~nxi"
exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:BuildLine
REM Thanks to ImDeepWithWindows for this nice trick of BuildLine
set "LineChar=%1"
if "%LineChar%"=="" set "LineChar=_"
for /f "tokens=2 skip=4" %%A in ('mode con: /status') do set "WindowColumns=%%A" & goto :GotColumnCount
:GotColumnCount
set "CharLine="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%A in (1,1,%WindowColumns%) do set "CharLine=!CharLine!!LineChar:~0,1!"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
endlocal
echo %CharLine%
goto :eof
::*******************************************************************
```

Comment: Oh ok, I see, thank you. I now get the result in the Command Prompt on screen. I might have made a mistake with the variables.. I thought that I could fill the %npver% variable and then it would remain in memory. So I could open a different Command prompt and ask Echo %npver% and get the result of the version. It is not the case when I execute the batch file, although when I execute the command from Command prompt directly, then my variable is populated as expected.

Comment: Oh nevermind :) I sent the result in a text file and now my variable is stored for future usage. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SabRina So your problem is solved ! In this case you should accept it as an answer ! Thank you ! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @SabRina here is another code in batch more elaborated to get file version of any Application from file list using WMIC. [Get_File_Version.bat](https://pastebin.com/uWscW7rU)