# Using Batch files to get the patch level build number for MS access

Tags: batch-file, ms-access, registry, office365

A recent Microsoft Office update broke a lot of MS access programs. To fix this we are having to revert the update on client machines. To automate this, i have attempted to write a batch file to do this, as reverting office 365 updates can be difficult, but different builds have different updates they need to be reverted to. To find out which version it need to be set to, i need to find out the patch/update level version/build number. I have looked in the registry but to no avail.
Is there a way to get the full build number? ie: 16.0.xxxx.xxxx

Comment: Take a look here  [How to get File version in variable using .cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942899/how-to-get-file-version-in-variable-using-cmd?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from an old PC under windows 7 (64 bits) with Office 2007 installed.

Just change the path of your office and execute it.

```bat
@echo off
Mode 75,3 & color 9E
Title Get File Version of any Application from file list using WMIC by Hackoo
::******************************************************************************
REM Just Change this Variable in your case and the script will do the rest (-_°)
Set "RootFolder=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12"
::******************************************************************************
:Main
@for %%a in ("%RootFolder%") do set "FolderName=%%~na"
Set "File_Version_List=%~dp0%FolderName%_File_Version_List.txt"
Set "ErrorFile=%~dp0%FolderName%_Error.txt
Set Extensions="*.exe"
If exist "%ErrorFile%" Del "%ErrorFile%"
If exist "%File_Version_List%" Del "%File_Version_List%"
echo(
echo          Please wait a while ... Process to get file version ...
set "BuildLineWith=call :BuildLine "
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CD /D "%RootFolder%"
@for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /b /s %Extensions%') do (
    set "Version="
    Call :Get_AppName "%%F" AppName
    Call :Add_backSlash "%%F"
    Call :GetVersion !Application! Version
    Call :Remove_backSlash !Application!
    If defined Version (
        (
            echo !Application!
            echo !AppName! ==^> !Version!
            %BuildLineWith%*
        )>> "%File_Version_List%"
    ) else (
        (
            echo Version is not defined in !Application!
            %BuildLineWith%#
        )>> "%ErrorFile%"
    )
)
If Exist "%ErrorFile%" Start "" "%ErrorFile%"
If Exist "%File_Version_List%" Start "" /MAX "%File_Version_List%" & Exit
::*******************************************************************
:GetVersion <ApplicationPath> <Version>
Rem The argument %~1 represent the full path of the application
Rem without the double quotes
Rem The argument %2 represent the variable to be set (in our case %2=Version)
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  'wmic datafile where "name='%~1'" get version /format:Textvaluelist 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Add_backSlash <String>
Rem Subroutine to replace the simple "\" by a double "\\" into a String
Set "Application=%1"
Set "String=\"
Set "NewString=\\"
Call Set "Application=%%Application:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Remove_backSlash <String>
Rem Subroutine to replace the double "\\" by a simple "\" into a String
Set "Application=%1"
Set "String=\\"
Set "NewString=\"
Call Set "Application=%%Application:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Get_AppName <FullPath> <AppName>
Rem %1 = FullPath
Rem %2 = AppName
for %%i in (%1) do set "%2=%%~nxi"
exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:BuildLine
REM Thanks to ImDeepWithWindows for this nice trick of BuildLine
set "LineChar=%1"
if "%LineChar%"=="" set "LineChar=_"
for /f "tokens=2 skip=4" %%A in ('mode con: /status') do set "WindowColumns=%%A" & goto :GotColumnCount
:GotColumnCount
set "CharLine="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%A in (1,1,%WindowColumns%) do set "CharLine=!CharLine!!LineChar:~0,1!"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
endlocal
echo %CharLine%
goto :eof
::*******************************************************************
```

So, I got a result like this one :

> ```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\ACCICONS.EXE"
> ACCICONS.EXE ==> 12.0.6697.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\CLVIEW.EXE"
> CLVIEW.EXE ==> 12.0.6606.1000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\CNFNOT32.EXE"
> CNFNOT32.EXE ==> 12.0.6776.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\DSSM.EXE"
> DSSM.EXE ==> 12.0.6606.1000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE"
> EXCEL.EXE ==> 12.0.6787.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\excelcnv.exe"
> excelcnv.exe ==> 12.0.6787.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\GRAPH.EXE"
> GRAPH.EXE ==> 12.0.6658.5004
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\INFOPATH.EXE"
> INFOPATH.EXE ==> 12.0.6735.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE"
> MSACCESS.EXE ==> 12.0.6735.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSOHTMED.EXE"
> MSOHTMED.EXE ==> 12.0.6500.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSPUB.EXE"
> MSPUB.EXE ==> 12.0.6780.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSQRY32.EXE"
> MSQRY32.EXE ==> 12.0.6606.1000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSTORDB.EXE"
> MSTORDB.EXE ==> 12.0.6713.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSTORE.EXE"
> MSTORE.EXE ==> 12.0.6713.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OIS.EXE"
> OIS.EXE ==> 12.0.6606.1000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE"
> OUTLOOK.EXE ==> 12.0.6785.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\POWERPNT.EXE"
> POWERPNT.EXE ==> 12.0.6775.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\PPTVIEW.EXE"
> PPTVIEW.EXE ==> 12.0.6654.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\REGFORM.EXE"
> REGFORM.EXE ==> 12.0.6650.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\SCANOST.EXE"
> SCANOST.EXE ==> 12.0.6650.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\SCANPST.EXE"
> SCANPST.EXE ==> 12.0.6650.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\SELFCERT.EXE"
> SELFCERT.EXE ==> 12.0.6606.1000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\SETLANG.EXE"
> SETLANG.EXE ==> 12.0.6606.1000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\VPREVIEW.EXE"
> VPREVIEW.EXE ==> 12.0.6600.1000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE"
> WINWORD.EXE ==> 12.0.6787.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Wordconv.exe"
> Wordconv.exe ==> 12.0.6500.5000
> ***************************************************************************
> ```